# jsoup image is not getting parsed

Tags: java, jsoup

i am using jsoup to retrive images from fallowing  web page 
{
http://www.jcpenney.com/dotcom/jewelry-watches/fine-jewelry/mens-jewelry/bulova%25c2%25ae-mens-stainless-steel-watch/prod.jump?ppId=180d97e&catId=cat100240089&selectedLotId=0514592&selectedSKUId=05145920000&navState=navState-:catId-cat100240089:subcatId-:subcatZone-false:N-100240089%20158:Ns-:Nao-0:ps-24:pn-1:Ntt-:Nf-:action-guided%20navigation&catId=SearchResults
}
my code is

```
String url = "http://www.jcpenney.com/dotcom/jewelry-watches/fine-jewelry/mens-jewelry/bulova%25c2%25ae-mens-stainless-steel-watch/prod.jump?ppId=180d97e&catId=cat100240089&selectedLotId=0514592&selectedSKUId=05145920000&navState=navState-:catId-cat100240089:subcatId-:subcatZone-false:N-100240089%20158:Ns-:Nao-0:ps-24:pn-1:Ntt-:Nf-:action-guided%20navigation&catId=SearchResults";


           Document doc= Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.120 Safari/535.2").get();


          String imgUrl=doc.select("#mapImageSjElement4 img").attr("abs:src");
```

it should return me image url but i am not getting image url.any suggestions?????
i want to retreive main product image which is on left side of web page.

Answer (score 1):

If you print the whole document, you'll see that that image and much more within the website is loaded by javascript scrips scattered all over the page. In order to get that image, you'll have to choose between the 2:

1. Use a GUIless web-broser like Selenium, Webdriver, HTTPClient; and upon full load of the page, get it's html content
2. Emulate the javascript by studying it's code, and retrieve the data you want

That would be a way to use the 2nd approache I mentioned without adding any extra libs to your project:

```
//Let's say you have the right script in a String
//variable named javascript.
String[] html = javascript.split("\n");

String imgUrl = "";
for(String line : html) {
    if (line.contains("imgUrl variable name here")) {
        imgUrl = line;
        break;
    }
}

//Now that you have what you want in a variable
//just split / substring it, untill you narrowed
//it down to what you want.
```

Comment: i am printing the html i retrieved actually the image is inside a dive tag and that div is not fetched in the html which jsoup returned me any ideas how to retrive missing contents. i have done different things like adding cookies , also used useragents but all in vain.

Comment: As I looked at it, it is loaded by javascript. Using Josup, you'd have to go into all the scripts and see how it loads it. If by any chance it's Jquery that gets the data directly from the DB, Jsoup just won't do it

Comment: i think image src is stored in a javascript variable i can get to the script tag but can i get a value stored in a variable inside that script using jsoup?????? if yes then how??

Comment: Jsoup won't help in getting something from javascript. you'll have to use String functions.. I'll edit my answer so that I can simulate a way to do it.